How to write the constructs arn into file and upload the file to the s3
I am working on cdk stack to create ecs services, i need to create the metadata file for code deploy (containing task role arn, security groups etc. (all of these are created in the stack)), but i cannot write arns to the file, because on synth time i get only tokens instead of actual arns and they are not resolved later(cause the values are in the file). How can i resolve this issue?

You can get ARN after the build, using Ref you can get the value, as in Output declaration,
Outputs:
stageOutput:
Value: !Ref
'Fn::Sub': 'Topic${Stage}'
